# How to read or download a file in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a React-Native project and I need to read the data from a file which is on Internet, so, I need to read the data from the URL or download the file, read it and then delete the file.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For native filesystem managing (creation of local files, deletion etc) you could use this module, https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs

For downloading/uploading you could either use the react native `fetch` 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html
or the above fs module.

Answer (score 1):

React Native provides the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for your networking needs. Fetch will seem familiar if you have used XMLHttpRequest or other networking APIs before. You may refer to MDN's guide on Using Fetch for additional information.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html